# Jquery - find all elements where the start element matches closest parent with that selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have HTML structures in a form system where a html node will have data-src="formname" and this will contain lots of html nodes with data-fld="fieldname". This would be easy to parse but sometimes a field can be a host of a subform that itself contains data-src and data-fld.

When I search for [data-src='name'] using jquery find selectors I get both the immediate data-fld elements and the ones contained in a child data-src, I only want the former, not the latter.

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/5k4hhv9x/1/) to demonstrate:

```
<div data-src="mainform">

  <div data-fld="field1">fld1</div>
  <div data-fld="field2">
    <div data-src="subform">
      <div data-fld="subfield1">subfld1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```

And the JS:

```
var result = "";
var find = "mainform";
var src = $("[data-src='" + find + "']");
src.find("[data-fld]").each(function() {
  var ele = $(this);
  if (ele.closest("[data-src='" + find + "']") === src) {
    result += "Child field : " + $(this).data("fld") + " ";
  }
});

$("#info").text(result);
```

The above code works, by virtue of that IF statement, I think it would be nice to be able to select "[data-fld]" where its closest "[data-src]" is the one I'm working on, and I wondered if (a) there's an inherent JQuery/CSS selector way of doing this or (b) is there otherwise a better solution to this code.

Not only because we want elegant code but also because asking for closest on every loop iteration is going to be a performance issue, possibly.

Comment: If you can use HTML5 tags, it'd be more elegant to use <main>, <article> or other appropriate tags instead of div soup with data-attributes that signify layout structure. It would allow you to use easier selectors. If performance is an issue and the structure of your forms doesn't change, forgoing jqeuery and just manually navigating the nodes might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

using immediate [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) selector

```
var result = "";
var find = "mainform";
var src = $("[data-src='" + find + "']");
src.find("[data-fld]").first().each(function() {
  var ele = $(this);
  result += "Child field : " + $(this).data("fld") + " ";
});

$("#info").text(result);
```

Comment: I guess you mean: `src.children("[data-fld]")` not `src.children().find("[data-fld]")`

Comment: Thank you, but sadly my fiddle was just an example and in practice the elements are not necessarily immediate children.

Comment: @user2728841 in that case you should go for src.find("[data-fld]").first()

Comment: Yes, see this fiddle update, it prints the subform field that we don't want: https://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/5k4hhv9x/2/

Comment: (which is obvious, because we never told it do ignore any child data-src instances).